# unable to fixed two side div fixed with responsive

Tags: html, css

I am unable to fixed two side div responsive.I searched many answer but nothing work for me.I am very week in css. this is my code.

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
}


/* For mobile phones: */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <!--left-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 well text-center col-3 left">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">My Profile</a></p>
        <img src="avatar3.png" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar"><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 10px">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px">Primary</button>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Interests</a></p>
        <p>
          <span class="label label-default">News</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
          <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
          <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
          <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <form>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <label for="comment">Status:</label>
                <tr>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="comment"></textarea>
                </tr>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-top: 5px">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
         </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-top: 5px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Post</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 rounded">
          <div class="well">
            <img src="avatar2.png" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
            <p class="text-left" style="margin-top: 5px">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-top: 5px">
          <b>Like</b>
        </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-top: 5px">
         <b>Comment</b>
        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--right-->
    <div class="col-sm-2 well text-center col-2 right">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
        <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want when I scroll page those two side div scroll some the fix that position but middle div scroll continuous.all div scroll until div content end.I am unable to do that with responsive.Please help me.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the two side bars to have fixed, while the content in the centre scrolls?

Comment: yes. I want scroll whole page until content end. When side bar content end those sidebar is fixed there position. like sticky position. two side bar sticky position.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center!important;
    position: fixed;
}
.col-sm-7 {left: 25%;}
.right {
    right: 6%;
}
```

Comment: no..It does not work..I already tried that.It is not responsive.

Comment: `.sticky {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 75px;
    }` using this It will stick there position but unable to do responsive